# Proof for onward travel in Non-schengen countries of EU

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, romania, bulgaria

I'm from Singapore and planning trip to Eastern Europe, landing at Romania and taking a train to Bulgaria and back to Singapore.

If I buy a one-way Singapore-Romania ticket and another one-way Bulgaria-Singapore ticket, is that sufficient proof of onward travel out of the non-Schengen area or do I need a ticket out of Romania?

I understand it's okay for between Schengen to another Schengen area, but these is between non-Schengen and non-Schengen.

On top of that, how about Schengen to non-Schengen and vice versa?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an onward ticket neither when entering Romania, nor when entering the Schengen area. Even if Romania is not yet a member of the Schengen area, they have already implemented the Schengen regulations in national law as a preparation for the accession, meaning that you face the same requirements as a foreigner when entering Romania as when entering the Schengen area.

What you *do* need is proof of means of subsistence, both for the period you are planning to stay, as well as for onward travel. You can find further documentation on [this information page of the Romanian Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://mae.ro/en/node/30320).

For both Bulgaria and Romania, the [reference amount](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_25_en.pdf) for means of subsistence is 50€/day with a minimum of 500€ per visit. Considering the price level in Romania and Bulgaria, be aware that this amount is unusually high compared to the actual living costs and even higher than in many West European countries like Germany, Netherlands or Denmark.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to proof that you have an onward or return ticket... So you can just fly to Bucharest Int. Airport. The Romanian officer will ask you ''what's your purpose of stay?" You will tell that you will make a Eastern Europe trip. Actually you can say just I'll stay just for a week in Romania... This is really not important. Such a country like Bulgaria or Romania, there is not tight border controls.

Just be relax and enjoy your vacation.

Comment: I would ask that you choose a different username, please. Your profile has no information in it as to who you are, yet by using that name, you lend (perhaps false, perhaps true) credence to your answer. More importantly, if you answer questions here, it could make this site look more "official" than perhaps we wish to be. Take this answer, for example... who says he needs no proof? You do and only you. Who are you? Why you're "Lawyer-European Union" so, voila, you MUST be right.... yet you've given no sources to prove you ARE right.